# Snake segments to follow a head in a snake game

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm trying to write a snake game. It's pretty simple, there's an array of snake segments which are Sprites and they all have `x` and `y` values. On each game loop, I want to update the snake segments based on user input.

Note: the head of the snake is defined as `this.segments[0]`. The first element of the segments array is the head.

It seems logical to me to update the snakes head based on the users input and then have each snake segment after the head update to follow it. This is my code so far:

```
public function update()
{
    // Update snake head
    this.segments[0].x += 10;

    for (var i:Number = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++)
    {
        // Set the segments position to be the same as the one before it
        this.segments[i].x = this.segments[i - 1].x;
        this.segments[i].y = this.segments[i - 1].y;
    }
}
```

Hopefully you can see what you're doing here. I'm trying to set the segments x and y values to be the same as the one before it, so it will "follow".

Problem is, when I run this code, each snake segment piles on top of the same co-ordinate and it looks like one segment running around. They don't follow, they group up on top of each other.

For me the logic looks solid, so what gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...

Reverse your loop ( do last segment going to first ).

And do the head last.

---

Basically, segment i is grabbing i-1's location which has already updated.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. You need to include the length of each segment in your calculation. Try something like this

```
for (var i:Number = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++)
{
    // Set the segments position to be the same as the one before it
    //include the width or height of n-1 depending on how you're moving segments[0]
    this.segments[i].x = this.segments[i - 1].x + this.segmants[i-1].width;
    this.segments[i].y = this.segments[i - 1].y + this.segments[i-1].height;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first item is the head right **this.segments[0]**

Then you decide to update the following segment (starts at 1) and you set it to the head's position. So **this.segments[1]** will be the same as **this.segments[0]**. Since it's a loop, every segment will be set to the head's position, that is why every segment piles on top of the snake. So you should loup from the end of the tail to the head to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not math wiz, but I found this pretty fun for some movement!

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var segments:Array = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){

    var circle:Sprite = new Sprite();
    circle.graphics.beginFill( 0x00ADEF, 1 );
    circle.graphics.drawCircle( 0,0, 10 );
    circle.graphics.endFill();

    segments.push( circle );
    addChild(circle);
}

stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, update );
stage.addEventListener( MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMove );

function onMove( e:MouseEvent ):void
{
    this.segments[0].x = mouseX;
    this.segments[0].y = mouseY;
}

function update( e:Event ):void
{

    for (var i:Number = 1; i < this.segments.length; i++)
    {
        // Set the segments position to be the same as the one before it
        this.segments[i].x += ( this.segments[i - 1].x - this.segments[i].x ) / 2;
        this.segments[i].y += ( ( this.segments[i - 1].y - this.segments[i].y ) / 2     ) + this.segments[i - 1].height / 2;
    }

}
```

Comment: side note: anyone know how to add some angle to this depending on your vector acceleration x,y?